# Excel.Workbook clicking cancel throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to save some data to an excel sheet.

I did everything correct, but now when I want the use to select a file to save one. I use this code

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileNameToSave, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

If the file already exists, the code produces a notification that shows: "do u want to replace the file?"

Is there any possibility that this message doesn't appear? Because I handled the existing files already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `Application.DisplayAlerts` property. You can set that to false. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for details.